# SoundCloud cocoa wrapper can't access resource without account

Tags: ios, cocoa, api, soundcloud

Trying to access a public endpoint in the SoundCloud API (https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json), sending nil for account to the SoundCloudAPI Library.

API response:

```
error: Error Domain=NXOAuth2HTTPErrorDomain Code=401 "HTTP Error: 401" UserInfo=0x7556ff0 {NSLocalizedDescription=HTTP Error: 401}
```

I quote their GitHub repository's general usage guide (https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI/blob/master/GeneralUsage.md):

> You can call this method without an account (nil) for anonymous
>   requests or with the account you get from [SCSoundCloud account].

Which as I can see in http://developers.soundcloud.com is a resource I am allowed to use without OAuth.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: You have to register you app and configure the API wrapper with your client id and key. Done this, you can make requests without letting the user login (passing nil as the account).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must append `?consumer_key=APP_KEY` to the URL of the request, thus example: `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?consumer_key=APP_KEY`

I found confirmation of this in their somewhat abandoned Google groups page here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/soundcloudapi/ptBbe_TWSj8

It seemed an odd omission from the general usage page on github and also omitted unless otherwise mistaken from their developer website.

**EDIT**

I did come across another piece of information about this, the developer site does mention a `client_id` GET parameter, this differs from the consumer_key however, it would be great if we could get confirmation on whether to use `consumer_key` or `client_id` for unauthorised, public API calls.

It also seems a little odd that the SoundCloud API library doesn't append this (which ever one appropriate) to the URL upon receiving a nil account argument. It seems logical to automatically switch to a correct api call if a user account object is missing.

Comment: My guess would be that consumer_key is used for OAuth1 tokens, and client_id for OAuth2 tokens.